# Selenium Jenkins issue

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, testng

I am trying to run my selenium TestNG xml file thru Jenkins integration. I have the following Shell command:

```
#!/bin/bash
set classpath="${WORKSPACE}/out/production/Test/Test:${WORKSPACE}/lib/*"
chmod a+x ${WORKSPACE}/lib/*.jar
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_121 /opt/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -cp "out/production/Test:lib/*" org.testng.TestNG ${WORKSPACE}/src/TestRunners/Smoke_Test.xml
```

This is the output of my build

```
[TestNG] Running:
15:19:22   /app/jenkins/workspace/Smoke_Test/src/TestRunners/Smoke_Test.xml
15:19:22 
15:19:22 
15:19:22 ===============================================
15:19:22 Smoke_Test_Suite
15:19:22 Total tests run: 21, Failures: 0, Skips: 21
15:19:22 Configuration Failures: 8, Skips: 42
15:19:22 ===============================================
15:19:22 
15:19:23 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
15:19:23 Finished: FAILURE
```

It ignores all my tests and fails. I am confused why.. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you please change your `verbose` to `2` (or) higher in your `Smoke_Test.xml` and run again. After it fails

```
15:19:22 ===============================================
15:19:22 Smoke_Test_Suite
15:19:22 Total tests run: 21, Failures: 0, Skips: 21
15:19:22 Configuration Failures: 8, Skips: 42
15:19:22 ===============================================
```

You should be able to open up the default reports such as `emailable-report.html` to find out what is causing the failures in configurations which is causing your tests to skip.